# Authentication Error while using Twitter API upload_with_media.json in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to post an Image using Twitter API upload_with_media.json in ruby.

This  is the Code I am trying to Execute:

```
oauth_key = {
                :consumer_key    => 'g0uxjlIYCyOHA', 
                :consumer_secret => 'XXXXXX',
                :access_key      => '2711184-rZePpS8eAV6zJRIB0',
                :access_secret   => 'xxxxxxxx',
            }

    tweet_text = "Test Tweet #{Time.now}"
    twitterUpdateXMLURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json"
    oauth_header = ROAuth.header(oauth_key, twitterUpdateXMLURL, { }, :post)
    oauth_header_params = { 'Authorization' => oauth_header, "Content-Type" => "multipart/form-data" }

# trying to create my own body since Net::Http doesn't support multipart/form-data
post_body = []
uri = URI.parse(twitterUpdateXMLURL)
# Create the HTTP objects
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header_params)

#    Add the file Data
    post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n"
    post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"#{File.basename(file)}\"\r\n"
    post_body << "Content-Type: \"image/jpeg\"\r\n\r\n"
    post_body << File.read(file)
#    post_body << "\r\n\r\n--#{BOUNDARY}--\r\n"

#    Add the JSON
    post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n"
#    post_body << "Content-Type: \"text/plain\"\r\n"
    post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status\"\r\n\r\n"
    post_body << tweet_text
    post_body << "\r\n\r\n--#{BOUNDARY}--\r\n"

request.body = post_body.join
# request.content_type = 'multipart/form-data'

if uri.scheme == 'https'
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
end

# Send the request
response = http.request(request)
```

But While doing so, I am able to publish the media but the text is not getting tweeted. Can someone please suggest what can be done to make this code work for both Media & Text?

Thanks, 
Naveen

Comment: Have you tried tweeting a regular tweet without an image? It sounds like this is an issue with your OAuth handshake in general -- not just this specific endpoint you mention in the question..

Comment: yes, without media, i am able to post the tweet using 'update.json' Twitter API. I saw twitter API examples too online, but couldn't figure out the exact change that needs to be done here to make this API 'update_with_media.json' work for media. This is the exact issue I am facing: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/33552 (in case it helps)

Comment: Can Someone please suggest some pointers to resolve this ?

Comment: This code is working now. Just Replace "#    post_body << "\r\n\r\n--#{BOUNDARY}--\r\n"

#    Add the JSON
    post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n"" with "#    post_body << "\r\n\r\n--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n""